# How to format REST endpoint for free-text search in my API?

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm building a RESTful API where consumers can access an item by ID such as: `/items/34`

Consumers can also search for items by fuzzy-matched name. What is the best practice for formatting such an endpoint? `/items/search/my+item` seems natural, but of course more experienced people than me must have already figured the best answer out.

Comment: Often you'll see `/items?q=some+search+query`

Comment: That makes sense and looks more extendable. Thank you!